# plot does not show up for an svm object and no error is returned as well

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to use svm() to classify my data. A sample of my data is as follows:

```
    ID  call_YearWeek   week    WeekCount   oc
    x   2011W01 1   0   0
    x   2011W02 2   1   1
    x   2011W03 3   0   0
    x   2011W04 4   0   0
    x   2011W05 5   1   1
    x   2011W06 6   0   0
    x   2011W07 7   0   0
    x   2011W08 8   1   1
    x   2011W09 9   0   0
    x   2011W10 10  0   0
    x   2011W11 11  0   0
    x   2011W12 12  1   1
    x   2011W13 13  1   1
    x   2011W14 14  1   1
    x   2011W15 15  0   0
    x   2011W16 16  2   1
    x   2011W17 17  0   0
    x   2011W18 18  0   0
    x   2011W19 19  1   1
```

The third column shows week of the year. The 4th column shows number of calls in that week and the last column is a binary factor (if a call was received in that week or not). I used the following lines of code:

```
 train <- data[1:105,]
 test <- data[106:157,]
 model <- svm(oc~week,data=train)
 plot(model,train,week)
 plot(model,train)
```

none of the last two lines work. they dont show any plots and they return no error. I wonder why this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Seems like there are two problems here, first is that not all svm types are supported by `plot.svm` -- only the classification methods are, and not the regression methods. Because your response is numeric, `svm()` assumes you want to do regression so it chooses "eps-regression" by default. If you want to do classification, change your response to a factor

```
model <- svm(factor(oc)~week,data=train)
```

which will then use "C-classification" by default.

The second problem is that there does not seem to be a univariate predictor plot implemented. It seems to want two variables (one for x and one for y).

It may be better to take a step back and describe exactly what you want your plot to look like.

Comment: Thank you for your response. First, I used factor(oc) and tried it before I posted the question and it did not work as well. Possibly, this is because of the second question you mentioned. I want a plot which shows the classification of the test set based on the "week" factor. I think week should be in the horizontal axis and the predicted value (fitted value for the train set) should be in the vertical axis. I am really new to SVM so I might be totally wrong

Comment: So week and the predicted values are both discrete, right? Are you trying to "plot" a table? It seems the built in plotting method isn't going to work for you. So what information do you need to extract from the model to be able to plot what you want?